# how to tell rest post data is invalid in spring

Tags: spring, rest

I have a post data request as the following,

```
{
   "doctorId":1,
   "userId":29,
   "sampleConditions":[
      {
         "conditionId":"14",
         "conditionName":"Acne",
         "conditionDate":"2017-01-31"
      }
   ],
   "labOrder":{
        "testId" : [1,2,3]
   }
}
```

what happens, if the client gives the incorrect key

```
"sampleConditionss":[
          {
             "conditionId":"14",
             "conditionName":"Acne",
             "conditionDate":"2017-01-31"
          }
       ],
```

Instead of giving sampleConditions, the client have sent the request as sampleConditions**s**.

How can i handle the request,

Comment: what have you done so far? share your controller and model code.

Comment: Return a 400 "Bad Request" status and that's all. This is the correct way of managing a malformed request. In all honesty, I think that Spring will manage it for you.

Comment: @javailike try to test this scenario and see how spring will behave, if you still don't know how to handle it, write down your code and the result of your test.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using springs the spring framework will return 400 and you need not do anything here